# what is the feature that must be provided in a webhost so the ipn works

Tags: paypal-ipn

I was useing a free web hosting , but now i want to find a new one that support the connection with paypal for ipn,see this topic to know what I am talking about
http://www.zymic.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=33328&st=0&gopid=141044&#entry141044

i alrdeay post this quetion but they told me "questions about free web hosting recommendations are off topic for Stack Overflow".

**so i am not asking a recommendation**.
my quetion is : what is the feature that must be provided in a webhost so my ipn script works?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question of "What is the feature that must be provided in a webhost so my IPN script works?".  The IPN is a POST back to your system, and then your system responds to PayPal's POST to validate the information.  You can set this up in different languages, and it can be set up a a windows or linux server.  Then its a matter of what you are wanting the IPN script to do with the information.  You would want to make sure you are sending the post to a secure url https:// Can you be more specific of what you are asking?